# Issue on Animating Div Background Color on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to animate the backgournd color of the canvas div on click event?

```
<div class="colbox" id="yellow"></div>
<div class="colbox" id="green"></div>
<div class="colbox" id="red"></div>

$(".colbox").on("click", function () {
   $("#canvas").animate({backgroundColor: $(this).css("background-color")});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Animating the background colour requires a jQuery plug-in. Have you included one?

Comment: Adding to what @AndyG said: you can also use jQueryUI to animate colors - have you included jQueryUI?

Comment: No I didn't know that , so jquery by it self cant do this?

Comment: Not really (not easily) you need a plug-in, although it can be done with [CSS3](http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css) if you have some aversion to plug-ins. If you are already loading the jQuery library then you might as well (IMO) use a jQ plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="colbox" id="yellow"></div>
<div class="colbox" id="green"></div>
<div class="colbox" id="red"></div>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 200px;
}
#canvas {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.colbox {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
#yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#green {
    background-color: green;
    left: 70px;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
    left: 130px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".colbox").click(function () {
    $('#canvas').animate({
        backgroundColor: $(this).css('backgroundColor') 
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arulpraba/HX6RM/)

Try including jQuery UI in the html you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css `transition`

Instead of `.animate()` use `.css()`

```
$('.colbox').on('click',function(){
   $("#canvas").css({'background-color':$(this).css('background-color')});
});
```

And then set you `#canvas` to animate the transition when change background-color with:

```
#canvas{
    transition:background-color 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:background-color 1s ease;
    -o-transition:background-color 1s ease;
    -ms-transition:background-color 1s ease;
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/3DRDL/